# BES overwrites outlook contacts How to stop this behavior

Tags: active-directory, blackberry, bes

We have a particular user who really likes to send around his V-Card from his blackberry contacts. To do so, he adds himself as a contact in Outlook and then emails the contact card as required. Somehow BES is grabbing his active directory record and overwriting the contact information with said AD record. Is there some way to prevent this?